how to query request if page numbers not known but page size is fixed ( say 100) in java
I have to call a method in which only max 100 elements of type Resource.Class can be verified in one check.
There can be many such elements in system ( more than 10,000 as well ) and there is no info about maximum number of such elements of Resource.Class in system. Only constraint is I can use max 100 such elements in one check run and have to check the condition for all existing Resource.Class elements. I have used pageSize as 100 in below snippet.
tried some query with setPageRequest to retrieve page of 100 elements in one run , but maximum number of such possible pages is not fixed.
 Filter filter = Filters.in("usedBy", "policy");

 Query query = new Query.Builder().setPageRequest(1, pageSize).setFilter(filter).build();

 Page <Resource.Class> pg = service.getPageByQuery(securityContext, query);

 doCheck(pg);  // perform check operation on each such obtained page

There are 2 concerns :

) How to know the iteration numbers for which need to run this query
2.) can there be some better approach anyway for this thing ?

There is a query in system to retrieve All elements of Resource class types , but that will slow down the API and also can break the response for large numbers , so not allowed to use that. I am bound to perform check operation on only 100 elements at one time.

You can get total number of elements from Page using getTotalElements().
Alternatively you can read until Page.hasNext() is false.

thanks for reply ,in system code ,  there is a LIMIT on maximum page elements to be 10,000 so that will only give 10,000 but there can be more than one page and again there is no confirmation of how many such pages

If by Page you mean org.springframework.data.domain.Page it have getTotalElements(). It will return total number of elements you will get if you read all pages.

no , we have some internally defined page class which is being used to query elements in all our codes, but the maximum totalElements in one such page is 10,000. is there some way that we can query from 1toN pages of each 100 size , untill there are no elements ? Thanks again

If it your internal API then only you know how to use it.
